# Несколько EditText с одинаковым ID

Tags: java, android

В LinearLayout циклом добавляется фрагмент, укомплектованный в другом .xml файле. Фрагмент содержит три EditText.

**Задача**: достать текст из каждого первого/второго/третьего EditText во всех фрагментах.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: `EditText.getText().toString();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В цикле бежите по `View` которые внутри `LinearLayout`, достаёте фрагмент, а у него обращаетесь к `editText`

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = initLayout();
int count = linearLayout.getChildCount();
Fragment f = null;
String reduce = "";
for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    f = (Fragment) linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
    EditText editText = (EditText) f.getView().findViewById(R.id.editText);
    reduce+=reduce+editText.getText().toString()+" ";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`((EditText)myFragment.getView()).findViewById(R.id.edt).getText().toString();`

чтобы на `getView()` не вылетал `NullPointerExeption`, при вызове этого метода фрагмент  точно должен быть добавлен. При получении значений из edt, по идее, он уже должен отображаться, просто будьте внимательны.